# Hazelcast new compact-serialization is not working with Hazelcast Jet Pipeline

Tags: hazelcast

I have tested Compact serialization is working well with Hazelcast Version 5.0.2 but when I try to use it with Jet Pipeline job then getting below error of serialization.

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.hazelcast.jet.JetException: Exception in ProcessorTasklet{tb-batch-compact/mapSink(mymap1)#0}: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'MyClass'
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:375)
> at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:1934)
> at com.hazelcast.jet.Job.join(Job.java:78)
> at HzCompactBatch.main(HzCompactBatch.java:57)

Comment: Could you please share a reproducer code, so that we can easily inspect the problem?

Comment: If it is not possible for you to share a reproducer, please share the configurations you are using.

My gut feeling is that the compact serialization is not enabled for the instances you are running the Jet jobs on (you can follow [this section](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/latest/serialization/compact-serialization#compactserializationconfig) to see the ways of enabling compact serialization)

Comment: I have tested it again with Hazelcast 5.1 BETA version and now do not getting serialization error. But all integer fields of class return 0 value, so not returning correct data and seems to be Compact-Serialization is not working properly.

Comment: I have update pom.xml file to use Hazelcast 5.1 beta dependency and seems to be working my sample application.

Comment: There might be bugs in the implementation as the feature is in the BETA state and we are continuously improving it. If you have any problems, it would be really great if you can create Github issues with enough information so that we can better track them and fix the problems quickly. Also, if you have feedback about the feature, we would like to hear that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested my application with Hazelcast 5.1 BETA version with updating pom.xml file to use Hazelcast 5.1 beta dependency and seems to be working my sample application with compact serialization.

I am posting this answer as it may be helpful to someone else.

Comment: Hazelcast fully supported  CompactSerialization with version 5.2. I verified it working well.